# string or binary data error even if 0 rows are inserted

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to insert data into a temp table by joining other two tables but for some reason, i keep getting this error `String or Binary data would be truncated`.

On debugging, I realized there are no rows being inserted into the table and it still throws an error.

To get rid of this, I had finally used `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF` inside the stored procedure and it worked fine. Now the issue is I cannot recompile the stored procedure with this settings in the production database and I want this issue to be fixed. And the other thing which is more irritating is, by default the `ANSI_WARNINGS` are actually `OFF` for the database.

Please let me know what could be the possible solution. It would be of great help.

Comment: What are the lengths for your columns, have you tried increasing them to see if the truncation error is resolved?

Comment: Yeah..It worked when i increased the length of the columns,but as said,i cant really change the length of columns in production,coz that would be affecting other clients.